# How to call a method in an abstract class

Tags: c#

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected virtual int getValue() { return 1; }
}
```

I want to call `getValue` method.

```
typeof(BaseClass)
    .GetMethod("getValue", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Invoke(null, new object[] { });
```

This code has  a error.

> Non static method requires a target

However, I cannot create instance of BaseClass because it is abstract class.
So, I am using dummy class which extends `BaseClass`.

```
class DummyClass : BaseClass { }

typeof(BaseClass)
    .GetMethod("getValue", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Invoke(new DummyClass(), new object[] { });
```

I don't want to create dummy class every time if possible.

Is there a better way?

Comment: If you need to create an instance then don't mark the class as abstract. You can still inherit from it as long as it is not marked as sealed. That is how abstract works though, you can never create a direct instance of an abstract class... ever. There is no way around that.

Comment: For what ever reason you are doing this it's probably the wrong way of doing it. You can't execute a method on an abstract class unless is static reflection will not make you br able to do it.

Comment: Normally, I do not create an instance of BaseClass.
But, I need return value of getValue in testing.
Should I change abstract class to standard class for only testing?

Comment: Calling a method of an abstract class is like asking "How does food taste?".
Developers use abstract classes to indicate that it makes no sense to use the base class, but that it is mandatory to derive a class from it.
If you need to call getValue for testing purposes, you have to remove the abstract keyword.

Comment: If its for testing then you need to test against a concrete class so any class that implements your abstract class.

Comment: Testing target is not a class inherited from BaseClass.
BaseClass also has static method `convert`.
I want to test this method.
An argument of this method and return value of getValue is same type, and it is a slightly complicated structure. so I want to reuse value of getValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the other comments that this should not be production code, but out of fun it can certainly be done:

```
public static T CreateAbstractInstance<T>() where T : class =>
    (T)Activator.CreateInstance(
        Thread.GetDomain()
                .DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("DynamicAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run)
                .DefineDynamicModule("DynamicModule")
                .DefineType("DynamicType", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class, typeof(T))
                .CreateType());

private static TResult AbstractInvoke<TClass, TResult>(string methodName) where TClass : class
{
    var method = typeof(TClass).GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    var elegate = method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<BaseClass, TResult>));

    return (TResult)elegate.DynamicInvoke(CreateAbstractInstance<TClass>());
}

private static void Main()
{
    var result = AbstractInvoke<BaseClass, int>("getValue");

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

There is probably some method to trick the compiler and invoke it without even creating an instance, but I was getting too many **Visual Studio** crashes to carry on investigating other methods. Expressions seems to lead nowhere as at the end of the day, it still had to generate valid code so no way to trick an expression into an invalid lambda.

If you reuse a singleton instance from `CreateAbstractInstance` then you shouldn't have overheads after the first object is created (beside reflection usage if you invoke non public methods).

I thought I might add this to the answer as well:

I notice the comment about using it in a unit test; if you are using **Moq** (and probably most of the decent frameworks), you can do this:

```
var bc = new Mock<BaseClass>().Object;
// Invoke whatever you want on `bc` with reflection or not.
```

Although be aware that if the method is `virtual` it will automatically override it so you won't get by default the base class logic, but it can be solved setting up the mock.

Comment: @blz You're welcome. By the way, if you're using it in unit-test, a decent mocking framework (I tried with Moq -> `new Mock<BaseClass>().Object`) will allow you to create a mock of the base class without having a concrete implementation and that might serve your purpose well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an open instance delegate.  Try this:

```
var method = typeof(BaseClass).GetMethod("getValue");
var func = (Func<BaseClass, int>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<BaseClass, int>), method);
int result = func(null);
```

Note: The above technique works by omitting the hidden `this` parameter in the member call.  This will only work if your method does not need to access the instance.  If you attempt to access the instance, you will get a null reference exception.

Comment: it does't work. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Something tells me `getValue` does more than return 1.  Does it need to access member variables?

Comment: `getValue` does't access to `this`.

Comment: code is here.public class Test
{
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        protected virtual int getValue() { return 1; }
    }

    public Test()
    {
        var method = typeof(BaseClass).GetMethod("getValue", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        var func = (Func<BaseClass, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<BaseClass, int>), method);
        int result = func(null);
    }
}